# Spark on K8's Issues loading jar

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to run a sample spark application(provided in the spark examples jar) on kubernetes and trying to understand the behavior. In this process, I did the following,

1. Built a running kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes (1 master and 2 child) with adequate resources(10 cores, 64Gigs mem, 500GB disk). Note that I don't have internet access on my nodes.
2. Installed Spark distribution - spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7
3. As there is no internet access on the node, I preloaded a spark image( from gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/spark:v2.3.0-gcs) into the docker on the node running kubernetes master
4. Running spark-submit to k8's as follows,

```
./bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://test-k8:6443 \
                   --deploy-mode cluster \ 
                   --name spark-pi \
                   --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
                   --conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
                   --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/spark:v2.3.0-gcs \
                   --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-pi-driver \
                   --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
                   local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.3.jar
```

However, it fails with the below error,

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
```

In regards to the above I have below questions:

1. Do we need to provide Kubernetes a distribution of spark? and is that what we are doing with?

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/spark:v2.3.0-gcs
```

2. If I have my own spark example, for say processing events from Kafka. What should be my approach?

Any help in debugging the above Error and answering my follow up questions is thankful.

Comment: There are two important parts. First it's the Spark image that contains the spark binaries to execute your jobs, that's the container.image parameter, and then there's your application. For your application you have two options, embed the application into the same spark container, which is what they do in the documentation, or use a remote address. The error you're getting might be caused because you are using "local" for the jar and the jar is not in the spark image you're deploying.

Comment: Hi @pacuna, yes you are correct. The jar is not present in the spark image. I am adding a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spark.kubernetes.container.image should be an image that has both the spark binaries & the application code. In my case, as I don't have access to the internet from my nodes. Doing the following let spark driver pick the correct jar.

So, this is what I did,

1. In my local computer, I did a docker build

```
docker build -t spark_pi_test:v1.0 -f kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .
```

Above built me a docker image in my local computer.

2. tar'd the built docker image,

```
docker save spark_pi_test:v1.0 > spark_pi_test_v1.0.tar
```

3. scp'd the tar ball to all 3 kube nodes.
4. docker load the tar ball on all 3 kube nodes.

```
docker load < spark_pi_test_v1.0.tar
```

Then I submitted the spark job as follows,

```
./bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://test-k8:6443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=5 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark_pi_test:v1.0 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-pi-driver --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.3.jar 100000
```

The above jar path is the path in the docker container.
For reference to DockerFile,
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile